# Seed data with relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I'm trying to seed my `Laravel 5.6` application through faker factory, I went through the [link](http://laraveldaily.com/laravel-two-ways-seed-data-relationships/) and little bit confused, As I have some basic static data, like for example I've a **company** model:

```
class Company extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes, HasDataSearchTable, HasSlug;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'code_link', 'slug', 'establishment', 'parent_id', 'website', 'updates', 'user_id', 'tracked', 'verified', 'active', 'premium', 'status'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at','updated_at','deleted_at'
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Variables\Company\Role', 'company_role_relation', 'company_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And a relational **role** model:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes  , HasDataSearchTable;

    protected $table='company_role';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'parent_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at','updated_at','deleted_at'
    ];

}
```

and respective database, I'm following the laravel convention, Now I want to seed the data:

I've particular set of roles which I'm seed in manually,

```
class CompanyRoleSeed extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('company_role')->insert([
            ['name' => 'Contractor', 'parent_id' => null],
            ['name' => 'Consultant', 'parent_id' => null],
            ['name' => 'Manufacturer', 'parent_id' => null],
            ['name' => 'Miscellaneous', 'parent_id' => null],
            ['name' => 'Owner', 'parent_id' => null],
            ['name' => 'Supplier', 'parent_id' => null],
        ]);

    }
}
```

For company I want to create factory so I did:

```
$factory->define(Company::class, function (Faker $faker) {


    return [
        'name' => $faker->company,
        'code_link' => rand(5, 10),
        'slug' => str_slug($faker->company),
        'about' => $faker->paragraphs(),
        'establishment' => $faker->randomElement('2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'),
        'parent_id' => $faker->randomElement(null, '1', '2', '3'),
        'website' => $faker->url,
        'user_id' => $faker->randomElement('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),
        'updates' => $faker->paragraphs(),
        'tracked' => $faker->boolean,
        'verified' => $faker->boolean,
        'active' => $faker->boolean,
        'premium' => $faker->boolean,
        'status' => $faker->randomElement('saved', 'draft')
    ];
});
```

And in company seed I'm having:

```
class CompanySeed extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(Company::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($company) {
            $company->roles()->save(); // Don't now how to execute here
        });
    }
}
```

Help me at place `$company->roles()->save();` What should I do over here.

Any guidance or improvisation welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query which roles you want to assign to the companies and related them to the created records like this:

```
class CompanySeed extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $contractorRole = Role::whereName('Contractor')->firstOrFail();
        $ownerRole = Role::whereName('Owner')->firstOrFail();

        factory(Company::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($company) use ($contractorRole, $ownerRole) {
            $company->roles()->attach([
                $contractorRole->id,
                $ownerRole->id
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

You can check the doc for relating records https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I have one doubt, I'm defining a Many to many relationship in my company model with role, so this `saveMany()` will work?

Comment: @NitishKumar, my mistake, I've updated the method with `attach()` for many to many.

Comment: Can I use random collection method to use any of the values, as this seems to me that every time it will have `$contractorRole` and `$ownerRole`.

Comment: Use the factory for that, look my answer I've done it like that :D

Comment: Or pull a random $contractorRole and $ownerRole inside the each function

Comment: @NitishKumar, this is just an example, as I see that you are inserting predefined roles in the database, so you can query them and assign random ones to each company.

Answer (score 1):

before answering your question you should know that Laravel's documentation explains how to do [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding).

But in order to save a related Model you first need to create a fake one, or in your case **relate a role you have already created**. In order to do this you could first create a Role factory using something like this:

```
$factory->define(App\Role::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $randomRoleAlreadyCreated = \App\Role::all()->random();
    return [
        'name' => $randomRoleAlreadyCreated->name, 
        'parent_id' => $randomRoleAlreadyCreated->parent_id
    ];
});
```

As you can see on Role factory I created I pull a random Role since you stated that you already created them manually, so if you choose one randomly then your companys will be related to one of your roles **randomly!**

Once you have: Roles created in DB, factory of roles, you could relate random roles to a company using the factory to **save a random instance.**

```
factory(Company::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($company) {
        $company->roles()->save(factory(App\Role::class)->make()); // Don't now how to do here
    });
```

**Update**
If you want to save multiple roles for each company you could do this:

```
factory(Company::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($company) {
        // Instead of 4 you could also create a random number 
        // using $numberOfRolesToAttach = rand($min,$max)
        for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) :
            $company->roles()->save(factory(App\Role::class)->make());
        endfor;

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm not having any random element in roles I have fixed data of `contractors, consultants, owners ` etc..

Comment: I know, thats why it will be chosen randomly from consultants, owners, contractors, etc.. Because inside the factory you are pulling ONE OF THEM randomly -> App\Role::all()->random()->name

Comment: So you mean `App\Role::all()->random()->name` will not create any new fake data, or will not create any repetitive data in `Role` model.

Comment: It will pull **one of your manually created roles**, because you are selecting the model, and random() returns a instance created on the db chosen randomly

Comment: Updated the factory so maybe it looks more clear now